# insert not working ,it redirect to view without saving the data

Tags: python, django

```
def insert_(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        form=ClientServicesForm()
        return render(request,"ClientServices/insert.html",{'form':form})
    else:
        form=ClientServicesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
        return redirect('/clientservices/')
```

I am trying to save data from a form but it is not saving to database ,it is rendering insert.html peroperly ,while saving it does not save database but without saving redirect to view

Comment: You need to handle the case when `form.is_valid()` is `False`. You should render the template with the invalid form and display any errors so the user can rectify them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure and I didn't test it, but I will try something like that :

```
## use messages
from django.contrib import messages

def insert_(request):
     template_name = "ClientServices/insert.html"
     form = ClientServicesForm()
     context = { 'form':form }

     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = ClientServicesForm(data=request.POST or None)

         if form.is_valid():
             messages.success(request, 'ok')
             form.save()
             return redirect('/clientservices/')

     return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: The view ClientServices.views.insert_ didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: This is the error i get when i submit the form